# Add element to if else statement. Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this if else statement that gives me an `<img src=""..../>` element as result. My problem is that i want the statement to give me a result as `<li><img src=""..../></li>`

I could just wrap the if stament around the `<li>` element but that would loose the purpose of what im trying to do. Is there any way i can add the `<li>` elements inside the if statement ?

Function

```
<?php if(class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')
    && MultiPostThumbnails::has_post_thumbnail('post', 'secondary-image')) {
    MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail('post', 'secondary-image', NULL, 'post-secondary-image-thumbnail');
        }else {


} ?>
```

result

```
<img src="..."/>
```

desired result

`<li>    <img src="..."/></li>`

The source code is

```
if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) {
new MultiPostThumbnails(array(
'label' => 'Secondary Image',
'id' => 'secondary-image',
'post_type' => 'post'
 ) )
 ;new MultiPostThumbnails(array(
'label' => 'third Image',
'id' => 'third-image',
'post_type' => 'post'
 ) );

 }
```

Comment: Can you provide the source code to `MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail` as that seems to be producing the output

Comment: @fullybaked Ofcourse forgot that :) its updated now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead wrapping `<li>` around if statement, you can use `get_the_post_thumbnail()` instead of `the_post_thumbnail()`. The function will return you the img tag as string but will not echo it.

You can do string manipulation/add tags and echo it whenever you want.

Source: http://voceconnect.github.io/multi-post-thumbnails/

Comment: @adnanyyousafch

Sorry to bother your, but i cant seem to find how to echo out the string. . any tips ?

Comment: how about `echo '<li>' . MultiPostThumbnails::get_the_post_thumbnail('post', 'secondary-image', NULL, 'post-secondary-image-thumbnail'); . '</li>'` :)